# Split string by the first N occurrences of a delimiter using boost::split

Tags: c++, boost, split

I know that maybe this is a silly question, but I didn't find an answer yet. Let's suppose I have the following string:

```
std::string str("1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10");
```

I would like to split it using the comma as a delimiter, but only at the first N occurrences. For instance, for N = 2 I should obtain as a result:

```
{ "1", "2", "3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10" }.
```

Is it possibile to do it with `boost::split`? I have always used it in the following form:

```
std::vector<std::string> values;
boost::split(values, str, boost::is_any_of(","), boost::token_compress_on);
```

which splits the string on *every* occurrence of the delimiter.

In case it is not possibile, can someone suggest me an efficient way to do it?
I would like to avoid dealing with regexes, i. e. I would like to write a function like:

```
std::vector<std::string> tokenize(const std::string& to_split, const std::string& delimiter, int occurrences)
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Interesting. I'm pretty wellversed with boost, but have trouble coming up with working code based on `make_token_iterator`, `find_first` and maybe `make_transform_iterator`. I'd be most impressed if anyone else showed it (_including_ `token_compress_on` of course). I bet I can make it work with a manually coded finder/predicate. But that doesn't seem at all warranted for this use case.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
find_nth(str, ",", 1);
```

from `<boost/algorithm/string/find.hpp>` to find the 2nd (or nth) occurrence of the character of interest.

Then use the traditional `substr()` on that possition.

Then tokenize the first part of the string boost::split.
And add the last part to the vector.

Comment: That doesn't [compress the tokens](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/split.html)

Comment: Fair point, @sehe - although I did not see it as a hard requirement in the OP. Davide - can you confirm that it's a requirement? Or are you guaranteed to have the string w/o any repeating tokens?

Comment: @MindaugasBernatavičius the solution you propose is enough in my specific case, but it would be nicer to have a more general solution, considering also repeated tokens. I will edit the post to specify this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `stringstream` and a modified locale:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

struct csv_whitespace : std::ctype<char> {
    static const mask* make_table() {
        static std::vector<mask> v(classic_table(), 
                                   classic_table() + table_size);
        v[','] |= space;
        v[' '] &= ~space;
        return &v[0];
    }

    csv_whitespace(std::size_t refs = 0) 
       : std::ctype<char>{ make_table(), false, refs } { }
};

int main() {
    std::string str("1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10");
    std::stringstream ss(str);
    auto loc = ss.getloc();
    ss.imbue(std::locale(loc, new csv_whitespace));
    std::size_t N = 3;
    while(N--) {
        std::string a;
        ss >> a;
        std::cout << a << '\n';
    }
    ss.ignore();
    ss.imbue(loc);
    std::string rest;
    ss >> rest;
    std::cout << "Rest: " << rest << "\n";
}
```

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/2yJ1MI)

The trick here is to treat commas as whitespace, which can be done in the `ctype<>` facet.